# Проблемы синхронного режима работы Webdriver.io при использовании Promise

Tags: node.js, async-await, promise, coffeescript

Пишу тесты на CoffeeScript с использованием фреймворка Webdriver.io (Wdio testrunner) с подключенным режимом sync. Согласно документации команды Webdriver.io должны выполняться в синхронном режиме. Однако в процессе работы при использовании Promise возникла непредвиденная проблема.

В качестве примера будет рассмотрен простейший тест, находящий на странице элемент по заданному селектору и выводящий в консоль текст найденного элемента.

Пример 1 - код без использования Promise

```
browser.url('... URL ...')
a = browser.$('... selector ...').getText()
console.log(a)
```

В этом простейшем случае команды Webdriver.io работают корректно.

Пример 2 - код находится в конструкторе Promise

```
p = new Promise((resolve, reject) -> 
    browser.url('... URL ...')
    a = browser.$('... selector ...').getText()
    console.log(a)
    resolve()
)
return p
```

Если команды помещены в конструктор Promise, то они по-преднему корректно выполняются.

Пример 3 - код находится в блоке .then после возвращения Promise

```
p = new Promise((resolve, reject) -> 
    resolve()
).then(() ->
    browser.url('... URL ...')
    a = $('... selector ...').getText()
    console.log(a)
)
return p
```

В консоль выводится следующее сообщение об ошибке: `"$(...).getText is not a function"` (Пример 3). Судя по всему, в этом случае команды Webdriver.io начинают работать в асинхронном режиме. 
Можно дождаться и обработать Promise с помощью конструкции await, но нам нужно выполнять код одинаково (синхронно) вне зависимости от места расположения кода (в Promise или вне него).

Также переключение в асинхронный режим происходит при использовании ключевого слова Await.

Пример 4 (Код примера 1 с использованием ключевого слова await)

```
await console.log('123')
browser.url('... URL ...')
a = browser.$('... selector ...').getText()
console.log(a)
```

В этом случае для корректной работы программы необходимо будет переделать весь код с учетом асинхронной обработки.

В качестве решения я могу писать все тесты в асинхронном режиме, но при этом код станет сложнее и больше. 
Можно ли работать с командами Webdriver.io синхронно даже при использовании Promise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответ подсказали на англоязычном stackoverflow.com

Для обеспечения синхронного выполнения функций в wdio можно использовать команду browser.call (). Ссылка на описание команды: https://webdriver.io/docs/api/browser/call.html